# Breaking for loops in C ends program

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

So, im a beginner in C programming and programming in general (i know a little javascript lol). Im trying to write a program that searches a integer array for a user's No. (number), log them in, and give them information about their account.

Note that im just making this for fun and practice, no particular reason.

**My problem:** I use a `for` loop to increment my `int i;` variable to search the array. The code:

```
main () {
    int userNo [9] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    float ultarCloud [9] = {12.04, 17.33, 8.9, 2.1, 13.75, 23.2, 25.0, 19.0, 5.34};
    int scan;
    int accountNo;
    int found = 0;
    int choice = 0
    for (scan=0; scan<10; scan++)
    {
        printf("\n\t\tPlease enter your Ultra-Cloud account No.:");
        scanf(" %d", &account);
        if (accountNo == userNo[scan])
        {
            found = 1; //statement becomes true
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found = 1)
    {
        do {...}
```

what happens is the program only accepts what the value of `int scan;` is when the user types their No. and will only end the for loop when a incorrect value is typed (something thats not in userNo array). and when an incorrect answer is entered it ends the program completely.

Am i doing something wrong? If you know what's wrong please tell me. Any advice is also greatly appreciated. I am using the code::blocks IDE btw. And just to let you know i havent been using stack overflow much so if im asking the "wrong" way then please let me know. thanks

Comment: Change `if (found = 1)` to `if (found == 1)` and what is `account` in the `scanf`?

Comment: The code doesn't compile, and would produce warnings pointing you to your mistakes if it did.

Comment: it does compile. if either of you dont know c programming scanf() is used to prompt the user :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int found, choice; 
found = choice = 0; 
for (scan = 0; scan < 9; scan++) 
{ 
        printf("\n\t\tPlease enter your Ultra-Cloud account No.: "); 
        scanf(" %d", &accountNo); 
    if (accountNo == userNo[scan]) 
    { 
        found = 1; //statement becomes true 
        break; 
    } 
} 
if (found == 1) 
{
```

I also believe that your printf statement meant to read, printf("\n\t\tPlease enter your User Account No.: ");

Also, I recommend you watch this short video on style:  http://cs50.tv/2012/fall/shorts/style/style-720p.mp4

Comment: Thanx. it actually is supposed to say "Ultra-Cloud" My make believe cloud storage system which is the information the user is there for. lol. but yeah didnt realise how much typos i had.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of problems.

> to search the array.

```
for (scan=0; scan<10; scan++) 
{ 
printf("\n\t\tPlease enter your Ultra-Cloud account No.:"); 
scanf(" %d", &account); 
if (accountNo == userNo[scan])
```

This is not how you search an array. You are asking the user for a new number for every spot the loop checks. To do a search you need to get one number to search for, and then search all spots for that number. As it is, the user could enter number 2 the first time around, when the loop is looking at the spot that contains 1, then the user could enter 1 while the loop is looking at the spot containing 2, and so on.

```
if (found = 1)
```

This is doing an assignment. Your compiler should be warning about this. If not, turn the warning level up. If it still doesn't, look for another compiler, or a lint tool that will catch this error. You can look at more warnings to fix [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0ee532bdb8863f1).

```
scanf(" %d", &account);
```

I assume that's a typo; Your program doesn't appear to contain a variable `account`. It has an `accountNo`.

```
for (scan=0; scan<10; scan++)
```

Your array has nine entries. This code will access `userNo[9]`, which is out of bounds.

```
main ()
```

This is legal in C89, but you shouldn't do it. It's not legal in C99. Use `int main()`. Also, C89 doesn't allow `//` comments. Choose a language standard and stick with it. Personally I'd take C99 over C89.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually using C11, according to the book i'm reading ("C programming absolute beginners guide") it hasnt really gone over the `main ()` function. I didnt realize all my typos! oops

Answer (score 0):

Change loop condition from

```
scan<10
```

to

```
scan<9
```

Your program is crashing from **array index out of bound** as your array ranges from:
`userNo [0]` - `userNo [8]`

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable called `account` in `scanf`. I think you meant `accountNo`

You are searching in `userNo` array and not in `ultarCloud` array.

```
for (scan=0; scan<9; scan++)
{
  printf("\n\t\tPlease enter your Ultra-Cloud account No.:");
  scanf(" %d", &accountNo);
  if (accountNo == ultarCloud[scan])
  {
   found = 1; //statement becomes true
   break;
  }
}
```